# redirect user to some URL on device resume

Tags: javascript, cordova, ember.js, cordova-ios

I am building cordova application using ember.

And on app resume event, I want to redirect user to path '/#/location' where i check user's location and updates latitude longitude.

Code is -

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = '/#/location';
  }, 100)
}
```

But its not redirecting to '/#/location'.

Can somebody suggest something about this? What i am doing wrong or how can i acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Listen this event after `deviceready` event!

> The [**`deviceready`**](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready) event fires when Cordova is fully loaded. This event is essential to any application. It signals that Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access.

```js
function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
  document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
}
function onPause() {
  // Handle the pause event
}
function onResume() {
  // Handle the resume event
}
function onMenuKeyDown() {
  // Handle the menubutton event
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Device Ready Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="example.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
</html>
```